# How to fix "Index" to show me the color

Tags: javascript

I have this table. I need to show the color in index (for the moment i get only de RGB). I'm waiting to get the color out of the index. How can i do that? Thank you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXeGl.jpg

```
function drawCoordinates(x, y){
       ctx.fillStyle = randomColor(); // Red color
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.arc(x, y, pointSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
       ctx.fill();
}
function randomColor(){  
              color='rgb('+Math.round(Math.random()*255)+','+Math.round(Math.random()*255)+','+Math.round(Math.random()*255)+')';

     return color;
}
var trHTML;
              trHTML += 
                      '<tr><td>' + color + 
                      '</td><td>' + data + 
                      '</td><td>' + results[i]["C2H4"] + 
                      '</td><td>' + results[i]["C2H2"] + 
                      '</td><td>' + results[i]["CH4"] +  
                      '</td><td>' + diagResult +
                       '</td></tr>';     
};
$('#records_table').append(trHTML);

HTML

<table hidden="true" align ="center" id="records_table" border='20'>
    <tr>
        <th align="center" width="50">Index</th>
        <th align="center" width="110">Data</th>
        <th align="center" width="100">C2H4</th>
        <th align="center" width="100">C2H2</th>
        <th align="center" width="100">CH4</th>
        <th align="center" width="200">Rezultat</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and less trickiest would be to just add a style to the table row.

`'<tr><td><span style="border-left: 7px solid ' + color + '">&nbsp;</span>' + color +`

I wouldn't use a background color for two reasons:

1. Some colors will make the text unreadable.
2. `background-color` isn't supported anymore for `TD`s in HTML5.

Comment: Done, Thank you verry much!